# Json not working through url

Tags: json, parsing

Hi all i am trying to setup a json feed.

i have been working from the following url

http://rest.users34.interdns.co.uk/index.php?format=json

this then outputs the json.

http://jsonlint.com/

but i cant grab the feed via jquery json like below

http://jsfiddle.net/isimpledesign/NTdBp/

im getting this error

```
1Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Comment: JSONlint gives me "Valid JSON" for this URL. You generally cannot retrieve any 3rd party resources from JavaScript due to the same-origin policy, that's why it does not work on jsFiddle (for this reason they have [their own HTTP responder](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html))

Comment: soz i have updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSONP needs to be wrapped in `( )`. So

```
{"jim":{"address":"356 Trailer Park Avenue","url":"\/clients\/jim"},"anne":{"address":"6321 Tycoon Road","url":"\/clients\/anne"}}
```

needs to be

```
({"jim":{"address":"356 Trailer Park Avenue","url":"\/clients\/jim"},"anne":{"address":"6321 Tycoon Road","url":"\/clients\/anne"}})
```

You can actually verify this, if you pasted each into a javascript console. The first is a syntax error, and the second is the object you are looking for. You will need the following tag to not throw an error:

```
<script src="http://rest.users34.interdns.co.uk/index.php?format=json"></script>
```